# Laravel Spark -- configure both flat rate + per seat pricing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I'm new to Spark and I've been playing in the sand for a few days, but am stumped on this issue. In Stripe, I've set up my dummy plan and its configured per the following:

```
$99 flat amount + $2/seat
```

Now getting this to match within Spark has been a hassle. I have combed the billing and teams documentation and there doesn't seem to be anything that allows for both consecutively. From the code below, I receive this in Spark `$99 / Member / Monthly`

Any advice?

My `booted` function looks like this. Is there a way to have both the standard plan price `$99` while adding a $2/seat charge (after *n* users)?

```
public function booted()
{

    Spark::useStripe()->noCardUpFront()->teamTrialDays(10);

    Spark::chargeTeamsPerMember();

    Spark::freeTeamPlan()
        ->features([
            'First', 'Second', 'Third'
        ]);

    Spark::teamPlan('test', '#censored')
        ->price(99)
        ->features([
            'First', 'Second', 'Third'
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Good luck. I'm in the same boat. Documentation is terrible.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: any luck yet? Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @MichaelNovello same boat here too... you had any luck with it?